# C# XMLTextWriter - XML 1.1

Tags: c#, xml, xml-1.1

I am working with a large XML file that deals with localization of strings in C#. I did not write the program that produces the XML, but I have access to the source and I want to modify it, as it currently outputs 1.0 as the version, but it contains illegal characters in the document.

Here is how the code is currently written out.

```
XmlTextWriter xr = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
xr.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; 
xr.Indentation = 4;
xr.WriteStartDocument();
xr.WriteStartElement("tlkFile");
// ...
```

However the [`WriteStartDocument()` documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestartdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that it uses XML version 1.0. I know this does not work, because I am writing a java parser that modifies this XML, and it can't load because it has unicode characters that aren't allowed. Specifically `&#x18;` which appears to be cancel. I'm not sure why this is here... the file is about 500000 lines long though.

I manually changed the header before my java parser grabbed it to 1.1, and it worked. Technically I could modify the XML as a string and then parse that, but I'd rather have proper XML instead.

I cannot find any way to change this. I can't really change the tool to use some other form of XML writing because it is a shared open source project that is used, and I'm not that great with C#.

Is there a trick to this?

Comment: How are you specifying the content to write? e.g. `WriteString`? [`WriteString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring(v=vs.110).aspx) has a few remarks about invalid characters.

Comment: XmlTextWriter internally uses the [`XmlCharType`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/XmlCharType.cs) when writing text data to the document. That type is confined to characters that are valid in XML 1.0. I very much doubt that you can even write `\x18` to your XML document using normal means.

Comment: The content that is being written is a decompiled localization file (Talkfile, TLK) that is used in unreal engine games. I can get my java to parse and write it if I change the header to use 1.1 manually. I looked around the documentation some more, and I don't think .NET even supports 1.l, which sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following process:

- Create a custom implementation of the IXmlSerializable interface
- Handle `&#x18;` using a custom method
- Use an instance of the implementation to read the document

**References**

- [How to Implement IXmlSerializable Correctly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly)
- [De-serialize whitespace characters using IXmlSerializable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhrubach/archive/2008/08/23/8613185.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace WriteStartDocument() with WriteRaw("<?xml version=\"1.1\"?>") and remove WriteEndDocument()?